# Find the general solution of $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+4y=\sin 2x+\sin x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solutions of $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+4y=\sin x$$ and $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+4y=\sin 2x$$
Hence find the general solution of $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+4y=\sin x+\sin 2x$$
I've worked out the first part to be $$y=A_1\cos (2x)+A_2\sin (2x)+\frac13\sin x$$
But I can't find a particular solution for the second part.
Then am I right in saying the final part is just the sum of the first 2 as the equations are linear?

Comment: then work out the particular solution of second example.

Comment: Do you mean: $$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 y}{\mathrm{d}x^{2}}+4y=\sin(2x)+\sin(x)$$ Rather than $\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}y}{\mathrm{d}y^{2}}$?

Comment: Where this $\sqrt 2$ comes from ? I guess it is a typo.

Comment: @Shaktal of course the OP means that!

Comment: Yes I did thanks

Comment: @claude I guess I accidentally square rooted twice, I think this is right

Comment: @santosh clearly my problem of 'I can't find a particular solution' will not be helped by you telling me 'find a particular solution'

Comment: i thought if you found the Particular solution of first problem, you will find the second one.

Comment: @santosh Well I tried the same method of putting y=asin(2x) but then I just find that -4asin(2x)+4asin(2x)=sin(2x), i.e. 0=sin2x

Comment: for meore, refer here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients

Comment: Your equation following "Hence, find the general solution of..." is incorrect. The sum of the two equations is $$2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + 8y = \sin x + \sin(2x) \iff \dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} + 4y = \frac 12(\sin x + \sin 2x)$$

Comment: @santosh sorry I don't understand how y=acos(x)+bsin(x) could be a solution to the equation $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+4y=sin2x$$  
Surely this equation for y would only ever give a solution to $$\frac{d^2y}{dy^2}+4y=csinx$$

Comment: @amWhy, the first equation involves $y_1$ say, the second involves $y_2$, and the one following 'Hence' involves $y_1+y_2$.  Don't halve the right-hand side.

Answer (score 1):

Since both $\sin 2x$ and $\cos 2x$ end up as zero, try $x(A\sin 2x+B\cos 2x)$.  That usually works.

Comment: $\sin 2x$ and $\cos 2x$ happened to be the Eigen functions of the DE or what do you call it ?? (+1)

Answer (score 0):

As you said, all that is left to do is find a particular solution of the second equation.

The following reasoning, in all honesty inspired by Wolfram, reveals a nice trick.

Consider $f(x)=xg(x)$, then
$f'' =2g' +xg'' $. If $g$ is such that $g''(x)=ag(x)$ with $a$ a number, then

$$
f'' + 4f= 2g' + (a+4)f
.$$

We want 
$$
f'' + 4f= \sin(2x) = 2g' + (a+4)f
$$

Trying $a=-4$, leaves $g=-\frac 1 4 \cos(2x) + D$. Consistency of the relation linking $g''$ and $g$ imposes $D=0$.

Hence our particular solution is $f(x)=-\frac x 4 \cos(2x)$.

Clearly a particular solution to

$$F'' + D^2F = \sin(Dx)
$$
is
$$
F=-\frac{x}{2D}\cos(Dx)
$$